# How to use a custom option from service.yml?

Tags: php, symfony

Is it possible in Symfony 3 to add any own option into service.yml file and then use it?

For example, I added into my service.yml file a *description*:

```
services:
    app.message_generator:
        description: 'Some description...'
        class:     AppBundle\Service\MessageGenerator
        arguments: []
```

If it is possible, how can I get this description from my service class?

I tried eg.:

```
$this->container->get('app.message_generator');
```

but I can't see the information.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get it from the container. You could by loading the configuration itself from the yml file.

Comment: It's a valid point this could be an XY problem; let us know what you're trying to do with it there, what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to have a list of services in my application with descriptions of the services.

Comment: You might be able to do what you want using a tag: http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html#adding-additional-attributes-on-tags But like several of the other posters have mentioned, it is difficult to see the use case for a description.

Comment: You want a service description for the programmer, or for some user of the site so they know what they're using? Neither of those belong in the service configuration. A service in that sense should be able to describe itself, so that sounds like an interface: `ServiceDescriptionInterface`, with one required method: `public static function getDescription();` Then each service that should be self-describing would implement that interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
services:
    app.message_generator:
        description: 'Some description...'
        class:     AppBundle\Service\MessageGenerator
        arguments: ['Some description...']
```

Obviously you need to add an argument inside your service.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
services:
app.message_generator:
    class:     AppBundle\Service\MessageGenerator
    arguments: [ 'Some description...' ]
```

and in your Service Class:

```
/**
 * @param string      $description
 */
public function __construct(
    $description)
{
    $this->description = $description;
}
```

But to be honest I don't understand why you would do it this way because

1. If you need a common parameter, use a [parameter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html) instead of a service argument
2. If you need a service specific constant, use a constant within your service.

E.g.:

```
class Service
{

const DESCRIPTION = 'Some description...';
```